# Identifying fullscreen gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, fullscreen

[image]Hey guys I'm trying to identify this javascript image gallery viewer on Tumblr, I remember seeing it from a developer but I cannot recall the name or how I got there. I tried googling but I didn't have any luck.

[image: Full Screen Image]

Thanks!

*edit: the main image is shown in the middle while the next/previous images are shown on the left and right edges but offset'ed

*edit2: added another image

Comment: A link would help so that we can view source.

Comment: Won't be able to do this, it is shown on the dashboard of tumblr, I tried looking at the source but the script is compressed and not easily identifiable

Comment: That one isn't opensource. [View JavaScript](http://s-league.net/ceemes/?page/show/s-global.js)

Comment: It's not that site, the screenshot is of the gallery in action. The site is just an image inside the gallery, you can see the next image to the right of it.

Comment: I've found something similar here: http://www.thefreshvince.com/demos/slidebox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an internal development at Tumblr using the namespace Tumblr.Lightbox (plain JS).

[view source](http://assets.tumblr.com/javascript/tumblelog.js).

There is also a [blog post](http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/9294264070/building-a-faster-lightbox) at Tumblr Engineering.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I know that there is someone who is working on a plug in that looks very similar to what tumblr has, I'll mark this as the answer if no one can identify the script in question.